# Find $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{x} (e^{-\frac{1}{x}}-1)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{x} (e^{-\frac{1}{x}}-1)$$

$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{x} (e^{-\frac{1}{x}}-1)
= \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}-1}{x^{-0.5}}
= \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{[e^{-x^{-1}}-1]'}{[x^{-0.5}]'}
= \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty}  \frac{x^{-2}e^{-x^{-1}}}{-0.5x^{-1.5}}
= 2 \cdot \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{e^{x^-1}x^{0.5}}
$$

So as $x \rightarrow \infty$, $\frac{1}{e^{x^-1}x^{0.5}} \rightarrow \frac{1}{1 \cdot \infty} \rightarrow 0$

Is this correct ? any input is much appreciated

Comment: Why students apply de l'Hopital when there is no need for it? $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\sqrt{x}(e^{-1/x}-1) = \lim_{z\to 0^+}\frac{e^{-z}-1}{\sqrt{z}} = 0 $$ since $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{e^z-1}{z}=1$.

Comment: @gegu The point is that here, you basically can recognize somewhere a derivative (at $0$), by definition. Using de L'Hopital then boils down to computing *two* derivatives (including the one you are looking for) to find *one* derivative.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio.They likely use l'Hopital when it's not needed because they  first  see its use in  some "mysterious" examples , and so they expect that it's the Rosetta stone for limits.

Comment: Average students are result-oriented. When I teach linear systems with the Gaussian reduction procedure, then I teach Cramer determinant's rule, after they use the last one even to solve $x+y=5;\;x-y= 3$. They need to be $sure$... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes your way is correct,but you can do it simply as  $$\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  } \sqrt { x } \left( e^{ -\frac { 1 }{ x }  }-1 \right) =\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  } \sqrt { x } \frac { \left( e^{ -\frac { 1 }{ x }  }-1 \right)  }{ -\frac { 1 }{ x }  } \left( -\frac { 1 }{ x }  \right) =\lim _{ x\rightarrow \infty  }{ -\frac { \sqrt { x }  }{ x }  } =0$$

Comment: thx for the interesting input, but isnt the limit of the last expression you wrote yielding an indeterminate form (trying to understand)

Comment: @gegu That is the point where you  can understand it by applying L'Hopital's rule. The result then is simply obvious.

Comment: @gegu Not all indeterminate expressions require L'Hospital's.$$\frac{\sqrt x}x=\frac1{\sqrt x}\to0$$Indeed, you should always check if you can solve the problem algebraically before attempting to use L'H.  (unless the assignment explicitly tells you to do so)

Answer (score 2):

Note the fundamental limit formula $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{a^{t}-1}{t}=\log a$$ and put $x=1/t,a=1/e$ to get $$\lim_{x\to \infty} x(e^{-1/x}-1)=-1$$ and then dividing by $\sqrt{x} $ we can see that the desired limit is $0$.

Answer (score 2):

I always prefer Taylor expansion to L'Hospital rule, as it is clearer and more generalized. For this one, write:

\begin{align}
\sqrt{x}(e^{-1/x} - 1) & = \sqrt{x}\left(1 - \frac{1}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - 1\right) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + o\left(\frac{1} 
{\sqrt{x}}\right) \\
& \to 0 \quad \text{as } x \to \infty.
\end{align}

It might be safe to say that all univariate limit problems/exercises can be handled neatly by applying Taylor's theorem with the Maclaurin remainder.